# CSS/Javascript not working in folders/directories when using re-write rules in .htaccess

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

I'm using the .htaccess file to make my URLs SEO friendly, but when I add a folder in URL the CSS and Javascript stops loading.

If I use this url it works (where id="123" and str="some-package-name"):
http://www.mysite.com/package123_some-package-name

```
RewriteRule package(.*)_(.*)$ packages.php?id=$1&str=$2
```

But if I use this URL, it doesn't (where id="123" and str="some-package-name"):
http://www.mysite.com/package123/some-package-name

```
RewriteRule package(.*)/(.*)$ packages.php?id=$1&str=$2
```

I'd prefer to use the directory-based URL if possible.

Also, is there any way to submit a form through .htaccess via the POST method to any other file?

Can anyone help please...thanks in advance!

Comment: You're missing the asterisks in the second example. Was that a typo?

Comment: Try to stick to one question per question :-)  The form submittal point is badly explained.  I don't know what you mean by reading this.  Better to think the point through and ask it in a clear way in a second Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You prefer to use use directory based url. Thats ok.

The problem is you are most likely using relative url-s for the css. Try to use domain relative or absolute url-s to css.

The reference for the css is probably relative in your header, so pointing to "style/asdf.css" results in "http://www.mysite.com/style/asdf.css" the first time, and "http://www.mysite.com/package123/style/asdf.css" the second time, as the browser searches for the css relative to the location of the current document. And the browser thinks that is's in a folder.

Use absolute or domain-relative urls for the css.

Absolute, starting with a protocol like http:// (good):

```
<­link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.mysite.com/style/asdf.css">
```

Domain-relative, starting with / (good):

```
<­link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/asdf.css">
```

Relative, starting with something else (in most cases bad):

```
<­link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/asdf.css">
```

This is also true for javascripts.

**EDIT**: Since I have checked your site, I have seen that every url suffers from this problem there. Try to click "Single user package" for a few times and see what it does to the url. That is the problem with relative urls. When you are using relative urls, the same url used form different folders points to different places.

If you are planning to use virtual folders in mod rewrite you must not use relative urls.

That means that lines like these will result in errors:

```
<li><a href="package3/night-delight">Night delight</a></li>
```

and

```
<li><a href="book-your-demo">Book your demo</a></li>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/validations-compressed.js"></script>
```

or

```
<li class="slct"><a href="index">Home</a></li>
```

also

```
<a href="index.php" id="logo" title="CGBroadband.com">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/template/fav.png" />
```

these will point elswhere from every page. So it's not just a css problem, it's a problem with every single link on the page.

In your case the easiest solution would **be putting a / before all your urls**.

**Edit**: Also check out this: I have found an other working solution that might be even easier: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/base

That means if you put

```
<base href="http://www.mysite.com/" />
```

in your <­head>, then all the relative urls will be relative to that! Neat isn't it? But I have heard someone complain about IE compatibility on this one so check it out on all browsers.

Comment: I already tried that and it worked fine but when i submit my site for analysis then the report showed my that this method was not recommended. Therefore i had to change my urls...

Comment: If the analysis shows "not recommended" for domain relative urls, than that analysis worths... little. Check out for example: http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/ -> BAM domain relative css and js (starting with /). And html5boilerplate IS about recommended techniques. I'm not saying this to save my answer. It is REALLY good practice and the only sane solution with url rewriting.

Comment: i have uploaded a prototype for testing http://cgbroadband.co.cc you can check it there...

Comment: I was right you are using relative urls. Since the appliction root is the same as the domain root, the line <link href="css/template-compressed.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> for example should be <link href="/css/template-compressed.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> This is true for all the link and script tags in your application.

Comment: MANY MANY MANY Thanks Bro...

I had been banging my head on the internet for this prob for so long...

many Thanks again...

Comment: You are welcome, but read my edits in the answer as there will be more headaches with the urls than just css and js. :) Also it is not considered rude here to accept an answer :)

Comment: It is the same problem. Just read the edited answer I have written for you.

Comment: Thanks its working...

And 1 more thing,

how can i change this 
"ErrorDocument 404 http://www.cgbroadband.co.cc/not-found" To
a smaller and auto detect form, i mean to say that when ever i need to upload htaccess file then i have to change my errordocument into this form...

Comment: I don't know exactly, but you might consider making an other question for it. Somebody will gladly help I'm sure.